# Unable to Connect to BLE device in Android 12+

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am trying to connect to BLE device in Android 12 using `connectGatt` method but It's not connecting.

Below Android 11 it is working fine.

1. I have added all the required permissions for Android 12 `Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN` and `Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT`.
2. I have tried all the transports AUTO, BLE and BR/EDR.
3. I am also allowing runtime permissions for Bluetooth.

The required device MAC address is found in discover callback. But, When I try to connect It's not receiving any callback and after few seconds It's sending me DISCONNECT BroadcastReceiver.

Comment: Could you show your whole manifest file?

Comment: Did you add the BLUETOOTH_CONNECT permission? [Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission#BLUETOOTH_CONNECT)

Comment: Yes I have edited my question.

Comment: Did you find any reason? seems have same issue. It takes multiple times to connect to device. On prev android(10, 8) version runs like it should

Comment: Maybe try to add the location permissions as well (ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION and ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)

Answer (score 0):

Many beacon devices still require location service for scanning.

That's why location service still requires in Android 12, giving permission to location `android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` and `android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION` also allows `android.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN` in AndroidManifest, and explicitly grant these permissions at runtime.